# jQuery scrollTop() not working in IE11

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-11

I have some code that simply activates  by clicking a button. When clicked, you are scrolled to that ID, that section of the site/page. It works everywhere except in IE11(the only version of IE I have). What is wrong?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery('#seemore').click(function(){
    jQuery('body').animate({
        scrollTop: jQuery('#pgc-2040-0-1').offset().top + 40
    }, 800);
});
jQuery('#order, .order').click(function(){
    jQuery('body').animate({
        scrollTop: jQuery('#panel-2040-3-0-0').offset().top + 40
    }, 800);
}); 
});
```

Thank you!

The site is here: http://jobbcv.se
It is the two red buttons at start I'm talking about.

Comment: Please recreate the issue on jsfiddle.net and post a link along with your code.

Comment: Does it help if you try `jQuery('html,body').animate...`?

Comment: You can watch it at http://jobbcv.se, its the two red buttons at start.

Comment: @showdev It does not help. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 4):

Change it to include html:

```
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $('#pgc-2040-0-1').offset().top + 40
}, 800);
```

And helpful hint, you can replace `jQuery` with `$`

Comment: @Johan I just tested it in IE11 on Win8.1 and it worked fine. You should try logging `$('#pgc-2040-0-1').offset().top + 40` to make sure it's actually returning a value. You should also log something inside the click event to make sure it's firing.