# jQuery animate to anchor script not working in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

```
$('a[href="#two"]').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var targetOffset = $('div[id="two"]').offset().top;
        $('body').animate(
            {scrollTop: targetOffset},
            1000
            );
    });
```

I have a code here that smooth scrolls to the div anchor. It won't function in IE (11). Works fine in Chrome/Firefox. Can someone help me out :D

Comment: have you seen this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29153607/jquery-scrolltop-not-working-in-ie11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work.

```
$(function() {
  $('a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 1000);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});
```